# How to convert floating point value to date time format in javascript

Tags: javascript, format, momentjs

I get a time difference from mongodb:

```
9.266666666666667
```

and rounded it off to two decimal places:

```
9.27
```

Now i want to format it to 00:00 time format. And i tried to format this using moment js:

```
moment(9.27).format('HH:mm')
```

But it returns:

```
08:00
```

which is wrong.

It should be:

```
09:16
```

Anyone have ideas? Thank you.

Comment: `a time difference` ... seconds? minutes? hours? days? what *unit* is the time difference?

Comment: 9.27 milliseconds after the Date epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00.009Z - converted to your timezone, it coould be any time I guess, depending on your timezone

Comment: Duplicate of [*How to convert decimal hour value to hh:mm:ss*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460303/how-to-convert-decimal-hour-value-to-hhmmss?s=1|122.6979)?

Comment: @JaromandaX—well, any time within +14 or -11 hours of that time. ;-)

Comment: I got my time difference with this code: db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$endtime", "$starttime"]}, 3600000]}
  }}
]) from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138877/how-to-calculate-timestamp-difference-in-mongodb-in-hours

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer based from this post:
[How to convert decimal hour value to hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460303/how-to-convert-decimal-hour-value-to-hhmmss)

```
var time_formatted = moment().startOf('day').add(parseFloat(9.266666666666667), "hours").format("hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

If 9.27 really needs to be translated into 09:27, you can parse it as a glued hour/minute:

`console.log(moment(9.27, "hhmm").format("HH:mm"))  // 09:27`

However, as others have pointed out, note that 9.27 hours is **NOT** 9h 27min.

Comment: If that is all that's required, then simple string replace, e.g. `(''+9.27).replace('.',':')`, would be far better than using a date library.

Comment: I edited my questions. I think it should be 09:16 since it is a time difference. Thank you.